# IBM Watson Assistant: Chatbot Entity Confusion over regular expression

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have an entity called "**@material_number**" in which two values are stored.

First value is "**material_number1**" with the pattern **(\d{3}).(\d{3})**

The second value is "**material_number2**" with the pattern **(\d{3}).(\d{3}).(\d{3})**

When the user enters a material number, I store the value with a context variable called "**$materialnumber**" and I set the value of this variable to "**?@material_number.literal?**". And at the end the bot responds "**Oh okay, the material number is $materialnumber.**"

The problem is that when the user enters a material number like "**123.123.123**", the bot thinks that the material number is "**123.123**". Basically it neglects the last three digits and prompts back "**Oh okay, the material number is 123.123**".

What can I do in order to fix this confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tested this and there are two problems. First, the dot (`.` is a special wildcard and needs to be escaped. Second, Watson Assistant does not support the full regex options and seems to match both numbers when typing in the longer number.

You can simply escape using a `\` and change your definition or use mine:

```
num1: (\d{3}\.){1}\d{3}
num2: (\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}
```

Because of the trouble with the regex evaluation I solved that in the expression itself. Watson Assistant holds the longer match as second value (if matched). The following expression looks if the long number, material_number2, has been matched, then extracts the correct value for it. It assumes that the shorter (incorrect) match is stored first.

```
{
  "context": {
    "materialnumber": "<? @matrial_number:matnum2 ? entities.material_number[1].literal : entities.material_number[0].literal ?>"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you data_henrik, I did as you said and now it doesn´t mix those two seperate values but now when the user enters "123.123" for the material number, the bot does not recognize it as a value of the @material_number entity. I don´t know what to do...

Comment: When I use **!\w** before and after the pattern value, the value becomes unrecognizable by the bot.

Comment: Henrik, i really appreciate your help. When I try to copy paste your code, Watson states that "Invalid JSON format, changes can not be saved" . I don´t really understand why though.

Comment: I reformatted the code for better copying, not readability :). It needs to go into the JSON for the slot (which you probably know).

Comment: Henrik, you really are incredible ! Now it is working all fine. Just one more question. What if i need to add one more value "num3" with pattern **(\d{3}\.){3}\d{3}**. So it will contain 12 digits. How should I deal with this now ?

Comment: New question added, as you requested ! :)