# IBM Watson Assistant: Chatbot Entity Confusion over regular expression 2

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created an entity called **@material_number** and this entity has 3 values which are provided below with their respective patterns:

**num1** with the pattern `(\d{3}\.){1}\d{3}`

**num2** with the pattern `(\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}`

**num3** with the pattern `(\d{3}\.){3}\d{3}`

In a dialogue node, if the bot recognizes **@material_number** it stores the provided user input under a context variable **$materialnumber** and then responds "Oh, the material number is $materialnumber".

The thing is that when the input of the user belongs to the value either **num2** or **num3**, the bot only stores the first 6 digits provided. For instance when the input is **123.123.123.123** or **123.123.123**, the bot only stores first six digits (seperated with a dot from the middle) and prompts back "Oh, the material number is 123.123".

By using JSON editor, it should be possible to overcome this confusion.

Comment: Will there be more patterns (num4, num5, ...)? Do you look for a specific solution or something more general?

Comment: For this specific entity, there will not be more patterns, sir !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383292/ibm-watson-assistant-chatbot-entity-confusion-over-regular-expression/52384352#52384352), you can nest [ternary operators](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#conditions-and-predicates-in-the-response):

```
{
  "context": {
    "number1": "<? @number1:mat3 ? entities.number1[2].literal : @number1:mat2 ? entities.number1[1].literal : entities.number1[0].literal ?>"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a genius ! I appreciate all your effort, sir. I also have asked a new question with the title "IBM Watson Chatbot: Handling Multiple Entities". I would be even more grateful if you can help me out with that one when you have time.